# What is the LD50 on once-a-day vitamins?

Tags: micronutrients, supplement, food-poisoning, minerals

Just because I want to know. For reference, here is the ingredient list for ONE A DAY Men's Health Formula:

- Vitamin A (14% as beta-carotene) 3500 IU 70%
- Vitamin C 60 mg 100%
- Vitamin D (as Vitamin D3) 700 IU 175%
- Vitamin E 22.5 IU 75%
- Vitamin K 20 mcg 25%
- Thiamin (B1) 1.35 mg 90%
- Riboflavin (B2) 1.7 mg 100%
- Niacin 18 mg 90%
- Vitamin B6 3 mg 150%
- Folic Acid 400 mcg 100%
- Vitamin B12 18 mcg 300%
- Biotin 75 mcg 25%
- Pantothenic Acid 16 mg 160%
- Calcium (elemental) 210 mg 21%
- Iron 0 mg 0%
- Magnesium 140 mg 35%
- Zinc 15 mg 100%
- Selenium 110 mcg 157%
- Copper 2 mg 100%
- Manganese 2 mg 100%
- Chromium 120 mcg 100%
- Lycopene 300 mcg